# Show same image on scroll and animate based scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, animation

I came across the Apple website where I can see the same image/design on scrolling up to some extent and also animation on scrolling to the bottom and up.

Ref URL: https://www.apple.com/in/macbook-air-m2/

I want to know how to implement those type feature.

Comment: I can't see any movement of images on this page at all. Maybe share a video?

Comment: I am not sure anyone can provide a full working answer here. Read through this article https://scrollsequence.com/how-to-make-scroll-image-animation/ It will give you the direction to follow to achieve similar results.

Comment: this is almost proposing to do a design work as bounty :)

Answer (score 2):

Animation on scroll is one of those problems with a bunch of ways to tackle it. My preferred method is using GSAP.

Here is a forum post with some more information: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/32782-video-scroll-animation/

Essentially you are embedding a video and then having each scroll position trigger the next or previous frame, playing through the video as you scroll. There are a lot of caveats but the link above is very in-depth so I recommend checking it out.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing such animations, so, there is no one answer.

But here are a few things that you can explore:

1. [Using HTML Canvas API](https://css-tricks.com/lets-make-one-of-those-fancy-scrolling-animations-used-on-apple-product-pages/)
2. [Using Parallax.js Library](https://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/)
3. Using JavaScript's Intersection Observer API as shown below.

I have used it to change classes, but you can easily change the backgrounds, move images around. You can also place images on top of each other, creating visuals Like on Apple & Samsung Websites where they show the insides of a phone while scrolling. If you try checking using Developer Tools, You'll find that usually Those Scroll Images are different images being placed on top of each other based on scroll.

**And if I talk about the Specific MacBook Page that you have listed, there they are using Videos & those Videos are being played & paused using JS in relation to Page Scrolling.**

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add("show");
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove("show");
    }
  });
});

const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
sections.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #131316;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 10%);
  margin: 2rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(50px) scale(0.5);
  transition: all 3s;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <h2>Section Head</h2>
  <p>Section Text</p>
</section>

<section class="section">
  <h2>Section Head 2</h2>
  <p>Section Text 2</p>
</section>

<section class="section">
  <h2>Section Head 3</h2>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend [scrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/) library by greensock. You can basically recreated the apple scrolling experience by configuring various animations and then deciding which animation plays once you hit a certain viewport height.

Here is a simple example: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/gOabMXv

Code ( by Greensock) below:

```
gsap.timeline({
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".shoe",
    start: "center center",
    end: "bottom top",
    scrub: true,
    pin: true
  }
})
  .from(".midsole",  { y: innerHeight * 1.5 })
  .from(".outsole", { y: innerHeight * 1.5 });
```

And here is a link to the docs: https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger